# class not found but class is created

Tags: configuration, xml

I am receiving the following error

`Fatal error: Class 'Ns_Module_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /Users/tony09uk/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 234`

I have added this file in my config and the exact same file path has been created for the setup file

etc/config.xml

```
<global>        
    <models>
        .....
    </models>

    <resources>
        <module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Ns_Module</module>
                <class>Ns_Module_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </module_setup> 
        .....
    </resources>
```

The file path is `Ns_Module_Model_Mysql4_Setup`

```
class Ns_Module_Model_Mysql4_Setup
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup 
{}
```

Why can't magento find this? I have checked the file paths are the same and checked the casing is the same, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have module_setup to start the xml section but prefs_setup is that another typo?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry. you probably won't believe that I reviewed this question before posting. I think I will copy and paste next time

Comment: could you activate `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` and set display errors then you should get a more complete error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the file permissions.  Remember the webserver typically runs as a different user so all files need to have read permission for all users.  Also the directory it's in must be similarly executable.

```
chmod a+r app/code/local/Ns/Module/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php
chmod a+rx app/code/local/Ns/Module/Model/Mysql4/
```

Comment: app/code/local/Ns/Module/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php and app/code/local/Ns/Module/Model/Mysql4 are returned with -rw-r--r--

Comment: I deleted those files and a recreated them, it now works. I have no idea why, I have re done the command you advised and it show the same permissions

Answer (score 1):

The class name in your file does not appear to match the name that Magento is looking for. You should update `Ps_Prefs_Model_Myql4_Setup` to `Ns_Module_Model_Mysql4_Setup` in your php.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make it more generic so that it would be something an answer that would suit others too, I will edit the question

Comment: Ah thought it was too easy ;)