# core_resource creates module_setup but install script is not called

Tags: xml, install, setup-script

I am trying to create an install file but Magento is not running that file, although it is putting an entry in to the core_resource table.

I have deleted the row which was created and loaded the page again. The row was re-created but the install file was not called (There is only and echo statement and die statement in that file to check if its working).

Trying to solve this problem I found [this question on stackoverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/class-not-found-but-class-is-created?noredirect=1#comment11989_8724) and have followed the advice, but I cant seem to get a result. When I break the config, I get a 404 page, I have changed the file permission so there is no problem there. Finally I have loaded the config, in there I have found `Ps_Prefs_Model_Mysql4_Setupcore_setupcore_writecore_read`, so Magento is doing something with my file, but I cannot tell what from this.

I'm hoping that it is a simple casing issue (which I cannot see, so below is my files and my config)

[image]

I also tried renaming the install file mysql4-install-0.1.0.php, that had no effect

```
<config>
    <modules>
       <Ps_Prefs>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Ps_Prefs>
    </modules>

<global>        
    <models>
        ........
    </models>

    <resources>
        <prefs_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Ps_Prefs</module>
                <class>Ps_Prefs_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </prefs_setup> 

        <prefs_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </prefs_write>
        <prefs_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </prefs_read>
    </resources>

    ............

</global>
```

In log/system.log I get this message

```
2013-10-01T09:36:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 8: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-10-01T09:36:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: &lt;/config&gt;--&gt;  in /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-10-01T09:36:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:             ^  in /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-10-01T09:36:14+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:83
[3] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/Mage.php:683
[6] /Users/tsimps/Sites/magentoDevTest/index.php:87
</pre>
```

Cache is disabled and has been cleared (just incase)

I am using version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Most probably your config.xml is not valid. Check if all the tags are closed. Also don'y put your install script in the folder `mysql4`. Move it one level up.

Comment: To add on @Marius comment, use http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp to validate the XML structure

Comment: Moving it up one level worked, but why does a prefs_setup still get added to the core_resource table?

Comment: @tony09uk. huh?. This is how it should behave. This means that your module was installed.

Comment: sorry, I mean when my install file was in the wrong folder, why is prefs_setup row still being created (I hope that makes more sense)

Comment: Hi tony, what happening to your module was that config.xml has declaration for set up and it was at correct location (prefs_setup was under sql folder) when it runs, it created the entry in your core_resource table. And the table was not getting created because script was missing at it's location.

Comment: you find an answer for this right? feel free to post it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row is created when you have an entry inside of your `config.xml`. If no setup file exists (or it is in the wrong place) magento just creates the row in the `core_resource` table and doesn't call any script.

This is a problem if you later add a install-script, which is never called, because the entry already exists.

So first write an install script, then add the setup to the `config.xml` and later add upgrade-scripts if needed,